# Question regarding object lifetime and deallocation responsibility

Tags: c++, memory-management

I'm sitting here with the following class:

```
class TagCompound : public Tag
{
   public:
      // [...] Constructor and other methods
      void insert(Tag *t);
      // [...] more modifying methods

   protected:
      std::vector<Tag *> _values;
};

TagCompound::insert(Tag *t)
{
   _values.push_back(t);
}
```

This is all fun and dandy and works with both stack and heap allocated objects of a class derived of `Tag`.

Of course, if the pointer supplied to `TagCompound::insert()` is allocated on the heap, it has to be deallocated somewhere outside. This means that every method that removes something from the vector has to return the removed pointer so the outside can free it again, if it has to.

I don't like this, it's messy and error prone if the caller forgets to `delete` it.

The other thing I tried out was simply assuming *every* pointer in the vector `_values` would be heap allocated and do the deletion in every function that somehow removed something from `_values` and have `delete` run on every remaining element in `TagCompound::~TagCompound`.

That of course completely ruled out stack pointers by causing an invalid deletion.

I also tried using `std::auto_ptr` but soon I found out that it doesn't work with STL containers. There's probably something from boost, but I don't want to use boost (or any kind of third party library).

Was I already on the right way with one of these methods, or is there some kind of black magic that works even better?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use tr1::shared_ptr (or std::shared_ptr if you have a 0x compiler) with custom deleters for statically allocated objects (no-op deleters in this case).

Answer (score 3):

One solution is to require the objects to be dynamically allocated, with lifetimes managed by **`shared_ptr<Tag>`**.

You can use `boost::shared_ptr` from the Boost library (there's also a `std::shared_ptr` in upcoming c++0x standard).

Then you have a vector of `shared_ptr`s and just let those `shared_ptr` manage life times automatically. A `Tag` object will then be destroyed automatically when the last `shared_ptr` reference to it disappears. And not before.

Cheers & hth.,